# How to localize date format in rails, form builders and error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, activerecord, internationalization

I've spent most of the day trying to localize dates in my application.

Reading this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html it seems that I18n.l(date) is the way to do it.

This is all very well if all I want to do is render date objects directly in my view. However a lot of the time I want to render a date in a form field:

```
= form_for @object do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :date
    = f.text_field :date
```

This seems to call to_s on the date object and use that, with no localization.

The first workaround I tried was to monkey patch the date class to use I18n.l:

```
class Date
  def to_s
    I18n.l(self)
  end
end
```

This seemed nice as I wouldn't have to remember to call I18n.l each time I render a date. However doing it this way breaks all my database queries as locale specific formats do not make sense in a query string!

To fix this I added extra logic to the patch:

```
class Date
  def to_s(type = nil)
    if(type == :db)
      self.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    else
      I18n.l(self)
    end
  end
end
```

However this STILL does not fit - because when using dates for validation errors active record seems to use the string value sent to the db.

Can anyone share with me how you would localize date formats consistently across your views, form builders and active record error messages?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Overloading Date's to_s method is a big no-no for me.

I can't think of a magical solution that formats dates differently depending on the context and manages to do that reliably ;)

I'd suggest continuing to specify the date formats only where you need them and possibly overwriting the `date.formats.default` translation in your locale file to make the format more palatable to your users (this should also fix the formatting in your `text_field`).